# Regex to match subsequent words

Tags: python, regex

In this regex : `test3\w+` I'm attempting to match the following two words after word `test3` in `'test1, test2, test3 match1 match2 tester'`

Here is my attempt :

```
import re

words = 'test1, test2, test3 match1 match2 tester'

# match the words match1 match2
# note these two words can be anything but are preceded by test3

print(re.compile(r'test3\w+').search(words).group())
```

How to capture the words after `test3` is matched?

Words `match1 match2` should be returned.

Comment: Why `tester` is not expected? Try `r'test3((?:\s+\w+){0,2})'` and access `.group(1).strip()`. Check for a match before accessing the group, it will be safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `regex` like

```
test3\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\s
```

**Explanation**:

- **\s** - matches any whitespace character.
- **\w** - matches any alphanumeric    character and the underscore.
- **+** - matches one or more occurances. ( So, \w+ matches one or more alphanumeric characters).

**Demo**:

```
>>> words = 'test1, test2, test3 match1 match2 tester'

>>> match = re.search(r'test3\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\s', words)

>>> match.group(1)  # returns what is matched btw first pair of paranthesis.
match1

>>> match.group(2)  # returns what is matched btw second pair of paranthesis.
match2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

```
test3\s([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)
```

This will give you two groups, one with `match1`, one with `match2`.

See https://regex101.com/r/NvPExD/1